# moment is not defined Angular Material DateTimePicker

Tags: angularjs

I'm using webpack and I can not include Angular Material DateTimePicker.
I get error 
bundle.js:50702 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

module.exports = angular.module("app.main", [
  .....
  require('angular-material-datetimepicker'),
  ....

Comment: moment is a javascript framework. Maybe you failed to include the moment.js in your file.

Comment: I included moment but still have the same issue

Answer (score -1):

`window.moment()` on the console if it did not return an object you may have failed to include moment.js in your file

Comment: module.exports = angular.module("app.main", [ ..... require('angular-material-datetimepicker'), require('angular-momentjs') ....
Now i have "Cannot find module "angular-momentjs", but i have it in my node_modules folder...
window.moment() return 'window.moment is not a function(…)

Comment: are you using a minified file? maybe you forgot to declare it in the grunt perhaps.